# Reconnect to debug process on Android using Eclipse with ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt

It's possible using eclipse debug perspective to disconnect from a debug process.

After this, is it possible to reconnect Eclipse debugger on this process ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, generally.
You can disconnect using the "Disconnect" toolbar button in the Debug view (looks a bit like a horizontal red lightning bolt!).

To reconnect, change to the "DDMS" perspective, select the process you'd like to (re)connect to in the "Devices" pane and click the green "Debug the selected process..." button at the top of that pane.

Comment: Yes that is one of the best things about the DDMS along with getting screenshots too!

Comment: If I could +10 this I would! The little green debug in the devices has been eluding for a day now.