# How to reconnect/reattach debugger to AIR mobile app on iOS and Android devices?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

*The question:*

**How does one reconnect/reattach their debugger to an AIR mobile app running on an iOS or Android device?** (The inverse relationship is also relevant-- where the app connects/attaches to the debugger.)

---

*Typical use case where this is needed:*

1. User opens app on device.
2. User clicks button to log in via Facebook.
3. The device's Facebook app is switched to momentarily and the user enters their Facebook login and authenticates with the Facebook server. **(Debugger connection is lost here)**
4. Original app is switched back to, where it can make use of Facebook login credentials.

---

*Clues I've gathered:*

The ADT utility from the Adobe AIR SDK is used to both package an iOS/Android app and connect an app 
to a debugger using either the "connect" or "listen" options.

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128fc240122-7ff1.html

The FDB utility from the Flex SDK can be used with Adobe's ADL utility to debug AIR apps. "Building Adobe AIR Applications" mentions the following (this is paraphrased):

> To conduct command-line debugging, you use the Flash Debugger and the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL).
>    - Flash Debugger is found in Flex SDK directory as fdb.exe
>    - AIR Debug Launcher is found in the AIR SDK as adl.exe
>   You cannot start an AIR application directly with fdb, because fdb attempts to launch it with Flash Player. Instead, let the AIR application connect to a running fdb session.

Renaun Erickson has a great article describing debugger connection during app launch, but he has replied to this question saying connection after that point isn't possible:

- http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/debug-air-apps-on-android-with-flash-builder-4/

The following posts seem to indicate this is possible with Android apps (I haven't tried them on my AIR app):

- [Android Reconnect Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994235/android-reconnect-debugger)
- [Reconnect to debug process on Android using Eclipse with ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583227/reconnect-to-debug-process-on-android-using-eclipse-with-adt)

---

*The answer:*

I'm interested in any form of solution to this problem involving any IDE or command-line utility, e.g., the "Flash Debugger" mentioned in Adobe documentation as a "command-line debugger", Flash Builder, IntelliJ IDEA, FlashDevelop, etc. As of now, the only debugger I've been experimenting with is the Flash Builder 4.7 debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed some apps for both iOS and Android using Flash Builder 4.5, 4.6, and 4.7.  They all work mostly the same when it comes to debugging.  When you start debugging on the device, Flash Builder will install a debug version of the application on the device, as well as set Flash Builder into Debug mode.  This allows to see trace statements in the console log and to see any errors that occur.  If you stop the debugger and run the application on the device it will not fire the Flash Builder debugger.  To use the Flash Builder debugger the app must be fired from debug command in Flash Builder.

Once the application is running it should stay running, until you turn off the debugger.  Unless, you have code written that automatically closes the application once the user moves away from the application.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Flash Develop IDE and Milkman Games' GoViral ANE to accomplish this, I have never experienced your issue.

Have you given Flash Develop a try?  If you can easily port your application over it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij you can recconect debugger without compilation/instalation app on device by using Flash Remote Debug configuration.